# how to upload image in the storage directory in php it gives me error "image is not uploaded"

Tags: php, image, oop, upload

Getting error while uploading the image. error is `image in not uploaded` kindly help me to figure this our.

```
class User extends DatabaseConnection{

    public function addNewUser() {
        $db = $this->getConn();

        $add_query = "INSERT into `users`"
                . "(`user_id` , `first_name` , `middle_name` , `last_name` , `user_name` , `email` , `contact_number` , `password` , `gender` , `date_of_birth` , `country` , `city` , `profile_image` , `created_at` , `updated_at`  , `role`)"
                . "VALUES"
                . "('NULL' , '$this->first_name' , '$this->middle_name' , '$this->last_name' , '$this->user_name' , '$this->email' , '$this->contact_number' , '$this->password' , '$this->gender' , '$this->dob' , '$this->country' , '$this->city' , '$this->profile_image' , NOW() ,  NOW() , 'visitor')";

        $db->query($add_query);
        if ($db->errno) {
            throw new Exception($db->error);


            $storage_path = "../storage/" . "$this->user_name " . "/";

            if (!is_dir('../storage')) {
                if (!mkdir('../storage')) {
                    throw new Exception("Storage Directory not created");
                }
            }

            if (!is_dir("../storage/$this->user_name")) {
                if (!mkdir("../storage/$this->user_name")) {
                    throw new Exception("User Directory not created");
                }
            }

            $upload = move_uploaded_file($this->profile_tmp_name, $storage_path . $this->profile_image);

            if (!$upload) {
                throw new Exception("User Image not uploaded");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should echo your `$storage_path`. I don't think it will look like you're expecting. Also, check your servers error log for a proper error message:

Comment: Which line does that error message come from?  Because it's not in the code you added

Comment: You will need to start basic debugging. Log variable contents into a log file or, better, use a server side debugger to step through your code. There are many tutorials available that explain how to get started with that.

Comment: `. "$this->user_name " .` contains a trailing space that I think is unintentional. You could change that to: `. $this->user_name .`. No need for the quotes there.

Comment: actually the problem is .. it make the storage path in mean storage directory but the image is not getting save in the storage  thats the mean problem have a look on the check  $upload = move_uploaded_file($this->profile_tmp_name, $storage_path . $this->profile_image);

            if (!$upload) {
                throw new Exception("User Image not uploaded");
            }       this is the prob the errir us "user image not uploaded"

Answer (score -2):

I think that the main problem here lies in the type of strings that you have used.

In PHP there are at least 2 string ways in which strings can be represented.

- single quotes -> writes everything as it is, e.g `'hello $world'` will literally print `hello $world`.
- double quotes -> prints out the variables that are embedded within, e.g `"$data"` will print out the value of the variable `$data`. Note data variables which are not "simple", or rather those which have qualifiers such as `$this->data` or even `$row['data']` **have** to enclosed inbetween the curly braces like so `"{$this->data}"` and `"{$row['data']}"` or else you will make it difficult for the parser to parse them, and hence you might get unexpected results.

Having said that, your code can be changed to the following...

```
$add_query = "INSERT into `users`"
        . "(`user_id` , `first_name` , `middle_name` , `last_name` , `user_name` , `email` , `contact_number` , `password` , `gender` , `date_of_birth` , `country` , `city` , `profile_image` , `created_at` , `updated_at`  , `role`)"
        . "VALUES"
        . "('NULL' , {$this->first_name} , {$this->middle_name} , {$this->last_name} , {$this->user_name} , {$this->email} , {$this->contact_number} , {$this->password} , {$this->gender} , {$this->dob} , {$this->country} , {$this->city} , {$this->profile_image} , NOW() ,  NOW() , 'visitor')";

$db->query($add_query);
if ($db->errno) {
    throw new Exception($db->error);


    $storage_path = "../storage/" . $this->user_name . "/";

    if (!is_dir('../storage')) {
        if (!mkdir('../storage')) {
            throw new Exception("Storage Directory not created");
        }
    }

    if (!is_dir("../storage/{$this->user_name}")) {
        if (!mkdir("../storage/{$this->user_name}")) {
            throw new Exception("User Directory not created");
        }
    }


    $upload = move_uploaded_file($this->profile_tmp_name, $storage_path . $this->profile_image);

    if (!$upload) {
        throw new Exception("User Image not uploaded");
    }
}
```

However if the problems persists. Then you have to make sure that the directory in which you are trying to move the uploaded file already exists and has write permissions for the user that is trying to write to it. usually on UNIX this can be achieved by `chmod 777 /path/to/directory`.

Comment: If you look at the query the OP have written, it is all inside double quotes so your change will actually produce syntax errors. More than that, you've put the quotes for `$this->last_name` in the wrong place. Your new double quotes would end the string. The query isn't the OP's problem. Or at least not the problem the question refers to.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson clearly that was a mistake. The least you could have done, was to edit it

Comment: Regardless of the last_name typo, that query will still produce syntax errors. Like I mentioned, the query is already inside double quotes so the OP's original version would actually work as expected. Yours won't. [Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/DJftK)

Comment: And I do agree with that. All I was suggesting was that you edit

Comment: That would more or less be editing your answer to look like the OP's code. What would be the point of that? Before the OP has done some debugging, any answer would just be stabs in the dark. Let's wait until the OP has updated the question with all the relevant information.